# SolrNet support for failover scanerio with SolrCloud cluster

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solrnet

Does [SolrNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SolrNet/) have built-in support for fail-over scenarios with SolrCloud?

I have 3 nodes in SolrCloud cluster, with external ZooKeeper ensembly. I use SolrNet client to communicate with Solr, but it is obviously uses connects to just one Solr node; when this Solr node I need to use another node.

I am currently using [ZooKeeperNetEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZooKeeperNetEx/) library to get the list of alive nodes from /live_nodes - but I am wondering maybe it is an overkill and SolrNet is already SOlr-Cloud-aware and will automatically switch to another Solr node if currect one dies?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Basic usage of cloud mode](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-usage-cloud.md) in the SolrNet documentation, you use a `SolrCloudStateProvider` with the zkurls when creating your instance:

```
var zookeeperConnectionString = "127.0.0.1:2181";
var collectionName = "collection_name";
Startup.Init<Product>(new SolrCloudStateProvider(zookeeperConnectionString), collectionName);
```

I'm guessing the connection string follow the regular zookeeper format, which means that you can give it a list of zookeeper instances to use by separating the hosts/ips with `,` between them (`192.168.0.1:2181,192.168.0.2:2181,...`).